# Automated EMail forwarding

Tags: email, forwarding

Is there a simple way, preferably using LAMP tools, to register a domain, and setup the email system such that it takes all emails sent to name@foo.com and forwards them to name@bar.com.

i.e., automate all the forwarding based on the username, so name@foo.com would forward to name@bar.com, across all usernames.

EDIT: Fixed the error.

Comment: this question doesn't specify very clearly what you want to happen... your example seems to contradict your question

Comment: my bad.
Forwarding would work like this:

bob@foo.com -> bob@bar.com
OJ@foo.com -> OK@foo.com
et al.

Comment: Email doesn't use web protocols so the A&P in LAMP aren't going to get you very far.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this by using Gmail's pop3 and forwarding features.